# Android opengl es 3 tutorial?

Tags: android, opengl-es-3.0

I'm trying to learn opengl for the first time. While implementing I see that I was trying to implement es 1 code on es 2 enviroment. After little search I found out that there is a new es virsion, es 3.
No tutorial for es 3 on google.

What should I do? **Learn es 2  or starting only with es 3?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es 3 is almost the same as Es 2 except that more functions were added. Start from Es 2 because there are many tutorials there for it. By the time you are done with it, you can then google Es 3 new features which will show you the new added features of Es 3 and how to use them.

Comment: es2 did the opposite, it removed functions. Thanks man, I was looking for an answer like this.

Comment: Yeah sometimes they remove(deprecate) some functions when they update an API. Most of the times, they make a new function that will replace that old one and even work better than the old one.